Add token to SysLog on Docker Compose
I have this docker-compose.yaml
services:
  app:
    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "udp://logs3.papertrailapp.com..."
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"

It works.
Papertrail also supports an extra security using token.
How to add it to docker compose?
